# ngFor not working in child component while child component used in Parent Component

Tags: angular

```
   *parent Component*
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    while accessing my child component in my parent component i am unable to 
   get the access if I use ngfor Directive
       <app-server *ngFor="let element of serverElements" 
     [elements]="element"></app-server>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  *Child Component(<app-server>)*
   <button> button </button>
```

If I remove ngFor directive in my appComponent.html, i am getting my button in my output. But when i User ngFor Directive Button gets disappear. please help me how to user ngFor Directive in  in my Parent 
      Component

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Does `serverElements` have a value? If it is null, undefined, or empty you won't see your child component.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like something is wrong the only thing that is out of place is that you have one extra closing `</div>` tag in the parent.